# Finding Odd Numbers of Divisors

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve a problem that is on [this page](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ODDDIV/). I think I have solved it as it gives me correct results but when I submit the code in the web page it says wrong answer. I don't understand where's my mistake. Could you please help me?

```
class Exercise 
{
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int divisor;
    int count = 0;
    int numbers = 0;
    int low;
    int high;

    // Get the input of the user
    public void getInput() throws IOException 
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter k, low and high");
        String line1 = input.readLine();
        String line2 = input.readLine();
        String line3 = input.readLine();

        divisor = Integer.parseInt(line1);
        low = Integer.parseInt(line2);
        high = Integer.parseInt(line3);
    }

    // Finding number of odd divisors for each number
    public void calculate()
    {
        if ((divisor % 2 != 0)) {
            for (int k = low; k <= high; k++) {
                count = 0;
                for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
                    if (k % j == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }   
                }
                if (count == divisor) {
                    numbers++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(numbers);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry. The divisor should be an odd number. Please try again.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Exercise obj = new Exercise();
        try {
            obj.getInput();
            obj.calculate();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your code expects a different input format than what they give you. Dunno if that's the only problem.

Comment: Math hint: Only square numbers have an odd number of divisors. You may need to take this into account to speed up your program enough to handle large test cases.

Answer (score 3):

From the instructions:

> The first line of the input contains a positive integer C (0 < C <
>   100,000), the number of test cases to follow. Each case consists of a
>   line containing three integers: K, low, and high (1 < K<10000, 0 < low
>   ≤ high < 10^10). K will always be an odd integer.

Your program does not take this input format. Your program expects a single test case with K, low, and high on 3 separate lines. It's supposed to take multiple test cases, each with K, low, and high on a single line.

Comment: hmm. ok and how should I correct my code to satisfy the requirement please? Could anyone post the code snippet as obviously I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: @user3054367: I've shown you the problem. The solution is up to you. Otherwise, how will you learn to solve these problems?

Comment: @user3054367: Hint: Loop over the input lines, parse each test case, and for each test case, run your `calculate` code.

Comment: Even this answer doesn't explain what you need to fix.. his program already checks for K, low and high on 3 separate lines just like it says you have to do it. It doesn't say anywhere you have to loop the inputs.

Comment: @SSpoke: No, that's how the OP *currently* does it, not how he's *supposed* to do it. K, low, and high do not go on 3 separate lines.

Comment: Oh my bad it says it.. Each case consists of a `line containing three integers`

Comment: Pretty much you have use to Split by `" "` in your program

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did it. Now it works exactly as the description. And it still says - wrong answer??

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  class Exercise 
   {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int divisor;
int count = 0;
int numbers = 0;
int low;
int high;
int test = 0;

public void getInput()
{
    test = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= test; i++)
    {
         get();
    }
}

public void get()  
{
    sc.nextLine();
    divisor = sc.nextInt();
    low = sc.nextInt();
    high  = sc.nextInt();

    calculate();

    numbers = 0;
}


public void calculate()
{
    if ((divisor % 2 != 0))
    {
        for (int k = low; k <= high; k++)
        {
            count = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
            {
                if (k % j == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                }   
            }

            if (count == divisor)
            {
                numbers++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }       
}

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     Exercise obj = new Exercise();
     try
     {
     obj.getInput();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
       return;
     }

 }
```

}